# Check if Geolocation is saved before returning value

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

### What I'm trying to do:

I need to request the user's location and save the latitude & longitude into an object. Since this may take some time, I need to occasionally check to see if the coordinates have been saved. I am using a setTimeout to check to see if the coordinates have been saved every 500ms. Once `

### The problem:

`checkCoords()` runs once and returns "user coords doesn't exist", however it seems like it does not continue to run.

What would be the best way to make sure `userGeometry` is returned once the coordinates have been saved?

```
EXAMPLE.GetUserGeometry = function() {
  console.log("Starting geolocation...");

  var userGeometry = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(save_location);

  function save_location(position) {
    var user_coordinates = {
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude
    };

    console.log(user_coordinates);
    return user_coordinates;
  }

  setTimeout(checkCoords(userGeometry), 500);

  function checkCoords(coords) {
    if (typeof coords === 'undefined') {
      console.log("user coords don't exist");
    } else {
      console.log("user coords saved");
    }
  }

};
```

Comment: if you want it to continue to run, you need to either change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` or call `setTimeout` from inside `checkCoords`. Also, `getCurrentPosition` is most likely asynchronous so if it takes more than 500ms your `checkCoords` will always say it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you need to do something if you never get co-ords?  Why not just do whatever you have to do inside `save_location`?